# how to change ios xcode "Packaging"-> "Product Name" by config.xml in cordova project?

Tags: xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have an cross-platform app built by cordova.

In the config.xml

```
<name short="DISPLAY_NAME">PROJECT_NAME</name>
```

By default in Xcode, the "Build Settings"->"Packaging"->"Product Name" would be "PROJECT_NAME".

[image]

I can manually change the "Product Name" in Xcode.

Is there any way that could set up in the config.xml?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The name of your app should come from the `<name>App Name</name>` tag in your config.xml. If you changed the name after adding the platform it might not get updated.

Please try removing and adding the platform again.

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios
```